# Bootstrap: Adding quotemarks around blockquote block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap for a project, I want to display some `<blockquote>`'s and have some big quotation marks at the beginning and end of the block quote element.

I am having trouble displaying the quotation marks around the blockquote and I'm not sure how to fix, I've even made all elements inline (which causes unwanted behaviour of multiple blockquotes in one line) but it still isnt work.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/O7udoOGQmu)

**HTML**

```
<blockquote>
    <p>Something really amazing goes here</p>
    <footer>Author</footer>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <p>Something really amazing goes here</p>
    <footer>Author</footer>
</blockquote>
```

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: none;
    quotes: "\201C" "\201D";
    display: inline-block;
}

blockquote:before { content: open-quote; font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Can you provide a mock up image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted the quotes to be at the diagonals of the `<blockquote>` element you could do something like this:

```
blockquote {
    padding: 6px 16px;
    border: none;
    quotes: "\201C" "\201D";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

blockquote:before { 
    content: open-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
} 
blockquote:after { 
    content: close-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; right: 0;
}
```

Basically positioning the quotes absolutely at the top left and bottom right corners.

Here is an example http://www.bootply.com/JS6qskU1tU

EDIT 1

I may have misunderstood your question, if you wanted the quotes to look just like normal text you would simply do that same thing you have but instead specify the before and after for the `<p>` tag not the `<blockquote>` tag like so:

```
blockquote p:before { 
    content: open-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
} 
blockquote p:after { 
    content: close-quote;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

example: http://www.bootply.com/BH80o3yLJp